# Please explain shared libraries vs. module libraries

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries, dlopen

I've been learning CMake recently, from which I've become introduced to the concept of a distinction between shared libraries and module libraries.

Some recent, relevant learning material (not the totality of it):
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/TYPE.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html
https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

I only became aware of this distinction after my introduction to CMake.

Prior to this, I was only aware of the distinction between shared libraries and static libraries. I thought that all `.so` files were shared libraries, but it now appears that a `.so` file may be either a shared library or a module library(?) And I was under the impression that the user had the *choice* of linking with a `.so` file or loading it (with `dlopen()` or similar functions). But now, per my in-progress learning, I'm forming the impression that the user needs to *know* whether his `.so` is a shared library or a module library, and in the case of the former, *must only link with it*, and in the case of the latter *must only load it*.

A point of confusion, for me, is that it seems one *can* either link to a `.so` file or load it, in the sense that a `gcc`/`g++` invocation that links to a `.so` file will return 0 (assuming symbols are properly resolved, etc.), while running `dlopen()` on that same `.so` file will also be successful.

My question is: **can anyone please explain the difference and origin of this distinction between shared libraries and module libraries?**

---

For simplicity, I've kept the question around *nix systems (i.e. `.so` files and not `.dll` files), but if the answer relates to the difference between Windows, *nix (and other systems), please let me know if the question can be phrased better accordingly.

---

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845984/difference-between-modules-and-shared-libraries), but I think this question is distinct because I'm trying to get at the *rationale*/history behind the distinction between shared libraries and static libraries, as opposed to just the fact that CMake facilitates the distinction (or makes the distinction more apparent to those, like myself, who had the impression that all `.so` files were shared libraries, and that it was a user's arbitrary choice whether to link to it or load it).

Comment: "can anyone please explain the difference and origin of this distinction between shared libraries and module libraries?" - It seems that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845984/difference-between-modules-and-shared-libraries) asks about the very same thing. Have you checked its answers? What is unclear in them?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - yes, I did read that question; my question is definitely related, but the answers at the earlier question don't cover the "rationale" behind the distinction, and whether the difference originated with CMake. From the (answers to the earlier question), I also didn't get a sense of when/why it is important/necessary to choose linking vs. loading -- that's what I'm trying to understand with this question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - part of my confusion is: the difference between static/shared libs is "clear": they have different file extensions, and the difference of linking a binary to a shared/static lib is also "clear." With shared/module libs, the distinction is less "clear" to me. E.g. it appears that you _can_ either link to or load a `.so` file, but CMake _enforces_ that you not link to a module lib. Long story short, my question is about the _rationale_/history behind the difference, as opposed to the _fact that there is a difference_. Open to editing/improving the question for clarity.

Comment: "I also didn't get a sense of when/why it is important/necessary to choose linking vs. loading" - [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388186/what-are-the-use-cases-of-dlopen-vs-standard-dynamic-linking) seems to explain that aspect. It seems that you have **many questions** about SHARED and MODULE libraries, but on Stack Overflow we expect a question post to contain a **single question**. Just search for every your question **separately**. If search for one of your question gives negative results, then feel free to prepare a question post specifically with that question.

Comment: Information whether a library is shared is communicated by its ELF Type.
`readelf --file-header library` tells either REL or DSO or EXEC, regardless of file extension.
It is developer's decision (trade off) whether they want to link it statically into a big standalone executable,
or dynamically and let the interpreter cope with dynamic linking at runtime.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I updated the post to focus on one question only. After a deeper reading of the related linked question, I agree that the answer is in there, but it is vague and not as comprehensive as @Corristo's answer. The answers at the linked question spoke in vague terms about on "_some platforms_" modules and shared libs could be different, but @Corristo's answer contained what I felt was a more comprehensive explanation involving `.lib` and `.dll` files on Windows, etc., which ultimately pushed me to properly understand this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux I don't think there is much of a difference, as you said you can still link to a MODULE library and you can also `dlopen` a SHARED library if you like to.

However, on Windows there is a difference. Shared libraries on Windows are usually composed of two files: The .dll file loaded when running a program that uses the shared library, and a .lib file used by the linker when creating the executable. Building a program that links to a shared library does not require the .dll at all, and similarly you can run such a program without the .lib file being present.

Because MODULES are meant to be loaded manually and not linked, a MODULE library will not create the .lib file, so on Windows you can't actually link to a MODULE library.